# Javascript to activate popup modal is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have created a form to capture name and email ID. The objective of my code is to capture the values of name and email and display it as a message in a popup modal on clicking the submit button. My code is unable to open the popup modal. Please let me know what is the error in the code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src='index.js'></script>  
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form class='form-control'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for='name'>Name:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class='txtArea' id='name'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for='name'>Email address:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="email" class='txtArea' id='email'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <tr>
            <button id='click-btn'>Submit</button>
        </tr>
    </form>    

    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="title">Display Message</div>
            <button class="close-btn">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p id='message'></p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id='overlay'></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.txtArea{ 
    padding-right: 200px;
}

#click-btn{ 
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color:white;         
    box-shadow: 5px;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)scale(0);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
    width: 50em;
    height: 10em;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal.active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)scale(1);
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal.close {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)scale(0);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal-header{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.modal-header .title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
}

.modal-header .close-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-body{    
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    font-size: larger;    
}
```

**index.js**

```
var openModal = document.querySelector('#click-btn')
var myModal = document.querySelector('#modal')
var closeModal = document.querySelector('#close-btn')
var pname = document.querySelector('#name')
var pemail = document.querySelector('#email')
var msg = document.querySelector('#message')
var result;

function disp(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var result = 'Hi ' + pname.value + '! Your mail id is ' +pemail.value
    console.log(result)
    msg.innerText = result
}

if (openModal){
    openModal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    disp(e)
    if (myModal){
        myModal.classList.add('active');
    }    
    });
}

if (closeModal){
    closeModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (myModal){
        myModal.classList.remove('close');
    }    
    });
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

I check your problem .The problem is  **transform: translate(-50%, -50%)scale(0);** in your css code .

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the modal with `var myModal = document.querySelector('#modal')` but you did not specify an id attribute for the `div` with `class="modal"`. Either you specify and `id` or you change the JS selector to a class selector.

```js
    var openModal = document.querySelector('#click-btn')
var myModal = document.querySelector('.modal')
var closeModal = document.querySelector('#close-btn')
var pname = document.querySelector('#name')
var pemail = document.querySelector('#email')
var msg = document.querySelector('#message')
var result;

function disp(e){
    var result = 'Hi ' + pname.value + '! Your mail id is ' +pemail.value
    console.log(result)
    msg.innerText = result
}

if (openModal){
    openModal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    disp(e)
    if (myModal){
        myModal.classList.add('active');
    }    
    });
}

if (closeModal){
    closeModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (myModal){
        myModal.classList.remove('close');
    }    
    });
}
```

```css
.txtArea{ 
    padding-right: 200px;
}

#click-btn{ 
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color:white;         
    box-shadow: 5px;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)scale(0);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
    width: 50em;
    height: 10em;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal.active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)scale(1);
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal.close {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)scale(0);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal-header{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.modal-header .title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
}

.modal-header .close-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-body{    
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    font-size: larger;    
}
```

```html
<form class='form-control'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for='name'>Name:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class='txtArea' id='name'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for='name'>Email address:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="email" class='txtArea' id='email'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <tr>
            <button id='click-btn'>Submit</button>
        </tr>
    </form>    

    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="title">Display Message</div>
            <button class="close-btn">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p id='message'></p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id='overlay'></div>
```